# Static page website not updating after a massive update, 13 hours passed

Tags: git, github, npm, command-line

I pushed a massive update with 3d models three.js and everything to a simple static website but 13 hours have passed and its still not updated, in the github repository there are two branches master and main
main consists of the older website
master consists of the new website
I switched the default branch from main to master after pushing:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should update not just the default branch, but the source branch for GitHub Pages too. :)

Comment: what do you mean by the source branch, please explain

Comment: Repo settings > Pages > Build and deployment > Branch - here you should select which branch you want GH Pages to pull your code from, to deploy your site. (Added it as an answer with screenshot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the default branch may not be sufficient, you may need to update the settings of your deployment process too.

If you are using GitHub Pages:

Under repository settings, go to *Pages*, then in *Build and deployment section*, select which branch you want GH Pages to pull your code from, to deploy your site:

[image: GitHub Pages settings]

Comment: also how much time will this take to update?

Comment: I'm not sure. I suggest to make a push to that branch again, to trigger the deployment.